# SQL query on supervisor table

Tags: sql, sql-server

What will be the SQL query in SQL server for the marked query on picture given below?

**Find  ALL the supervisors (direct and indirect) of Bob**
[image]

Comment: The information given in your question is not enough to give you an answer, as it does not describe any of the relations between the two tables, or even if they are tables or just columns of the same table.

Comment: Do it in a recursive cte, essentially you union 2 queries where supervisor =person and you refer to the cte in the second one

Comment: It is the only table with two columns. @LudvigRydahl

Comment: In SQL Server, what you are looking for is call Common Table Expressions

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT Supervisor
FROM t
WHERE Person='Bob'
UNION ALL
SELECT tt.Supervisor
FROM t tt
INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.Supervisor = tt.Person
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

[Test](http://rextester.com/BDLK8832)

Comment: I am having two errors on this: 1) invalid column name Person and 2)Ambiguous column name Supervisor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Person NVARCHAR(30) , Supervisor NVARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('Bob','Alice'),('Mary','Susan'),('Alice','David'),('David','Mary');

select T.Supervisor
from @T T
Where T.Person = 'Bob'
union all
Select TT.Supervisor
From @T TT inner join @T A
on  A.Supervisor = TT.Person
```

Comment: This query wouldn't work for any person other than Bob. All this does is assume that Bob isn't supervisor of anyone else and then lists out all the supervisors. Is this the best approach? Can't a more general solution be found?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select T.supervisor, F.supervisor 
from emp_Super T, emp_Super F 
where T.person = 'Bob' 
  and T.supervisor = F.person;
```

Comment: The query is suppose to return all the supervisors of Bob, both direct and indirect. Not just "Alice" and "David". Apart from that I recommend using SQL ANSI-92 syntax instead of the older syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.supervisor, F.supervisor, K.supervisor, M.supervisor
FROM emp_super T, emp_super F, emp_super K, emp_super M
WHERE
 T.Person = "Bob" AND
 F.Person = T.Supervisor AND 
 K.person = F.Supervisor AND
 M.Person = K.Supervisor ;
```

It will work for this table at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
creat table supervisors 
(
  person char(20) not null,
  supervisor char(20) not null,
  constraint supervisor-pk primary kye(supervisor),
);
instr into supervisors
value('Bob','Alice');

instr into supervisors
value('Mary','Susan');

instr into supervisors
value('Alice','David');

instr into supervisors
value('David','Mary');

select supervisor 
from emp-super 
where person='bob';

select supervisor 
from emp-super 
where person= ( select supervisor from emp-super
where person='bob');

select T.supervisor, F.supervisor, K.supervisor, M.supervisor
from emp_super T, emp_super F, emp_super K, emp_super M
where T.Person = "Bob" AND F.Person = T.Supervisor AND  K.person = F.Supervisor AND M.Person = K.Supervisor ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution that works in a recursive way for any `person`:

```
WITH SupervisorHierarchy (person, supervisor) AS (
  SELECT w.person, w.supervisor
  FROM works w
  WHERE w.person = 'Bob'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT w2.person, w2.supervisor
  FROM works w2
  JOIN SupervisorHierarchy sh ON w2.person = sh.supervisor
)
SELECT DISTINCT supervisor
FROM SupervisorHierarchy;
```

1. The `SupervisorHierarchy` begins with the tuple **(Bob, Alice)** that we've found in the statement *before* `UNION ALL`.
2. Then, it searches recursively the supervisor like this: it joins the `works` table and tries to match a person with the last tuple's supervisor that got in `SupervisorHierarchy`, which is **Alice**. So, the 2nd tuple that gets inserted, is **(Alice, David)**.
3. It then does the same for **David**, which *he* is now the `sh.supervisor`. It joins the `works` table and tries to match a person with this name.
4. It finally goes to **Susan** where she has no supervisor, and it returns the results.

Answer (score -1):

1= select supervisor 
     from emp-super
     where person='bob';

2= select supervisor
      From emp-super
      Where person=
      ( Select supervisor
         from emp-super
         where person='bob');